# Is my implementation of type/subtype design pattern (for mutually exclusive subclasses) correct?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012, subtypes

#### Introduction

In order for this question to be useful for future readers I will use the generic data model to illustrate the problems I face.

Our data model consists of two entities, which shall be labeled as `A` and `B`. In order to keep things simple, all their attributes will be of `int` type.

Entity `A` has following attributes: `D` and `X`;
Entity `B` has following attributes: `D` and `Y`;

#### Problem

Since both entities share common attribute `D`, I have decided to apply *type/subtype* design.

I am not sure that my implementation is correct, thus I am asking here for design review.

#### My Implementation

```
-- lookup table for discriminator column
CREATE TABLE ClassType
(
  ClassTypeID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Class_Description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- inserting types A and B from our example 
INSERT INTO ClassType (Class_Description)
VALUES ('A'), ('B');

-- creating base class table
CREATE TABLE BaseClass
(
  BaseClass_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ClassTypeID INT NOT NULL, -- FK to Type
  D int
);

ALTER TABLE BaseClass
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BaseClass_ClassType]
FOREIGN KEY (ClassTypeID)
REFERENCES ClassType (ClassTypeID);

-- we need this constraint in order for foreign keys in subclasses to work
ALTER TABLE BaseClass
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AltKey]
UNIQUE (BaseClass_ID, ClassTypeID);

-- creating subclasses:
CREATE TABLE SubclassA
(
  BaseClass_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  X int,
  ClassTypeID AS 1 PERSISTED -- calculated field, ensures integrity
);

ALTER TABLE SubclassA
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_SubclassA_BaseClass]
FOREIGN KEY (BaseClass_ID, ClassTypeID)
REFERENCES BaseClass (BaseClass_ID, ClassTypeID);

CREATE TABLE SubclassB
(
  BaseClass_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Y int,
  ClassTypeID AS 2 PERSISTED -- calculated field, ensures integrity
);

ALTER TABLE SubclassB
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_SubclassB_BaseClass]
FOREIGN KEY (BaseClass_ID, ClassTypeID)
REFERENCES BaseClass (BaseClass_ID, ClassTypeID);
```

This is how the database diagram looks in SQL Server 2012:

[image: Database Diagram]

#### Questions

- Did I make any mistakes in my implementation?
- Apart from making class type (in subclass tables) calculated and persisted, is there anything else I can do to prevent mistakes during `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the design looks great. Minor notes:

- You could use `TINYINT`, instead of the `INT` for the `ClassTypeID`. Or even `CHAR(1)` and have `'A'` and `'B'` instead of `1` and `2`. 1 byte instead of 4 means you are saving **3 bytes in every row**, in all 3 tables and in every index that includes `ClassTypeID` - which would be every index on these tables, if `ClassTypeID` is part of the clustered key.
- The attributes of both the base and the subtype tables could be `NOT NULL`. I don't see why you would want them nullable, with this design.
- It might be better (but needs thorough testing) if you had both the `UNIQUE` constraint of the base table and the 2 foreign keys that reference it defined with the reverse order `(ClassTypeID, BaseClass_ID)`. This is more an indexing / physical design suggestion, it doesn't alter the logical design. I would experiment with having the clustered key in the base table using this order, too.

Comment: Wow, so many useful suggestions... I have upvoted your answer. I will probably follow your advice and use `char(1)` instead of `int` as space preservation is high on my list. I will also go with your advice and make fields `NOT NULL`. I do not quite understand your 3rd point but would like to learn about it. Can you suggest some online resources (I apologize for asking, but I am software developer so I would need to learn more about your 3rd suggestion) ?

Comment: TINYINT is also 1 byte but CHAR(1) is more readable, when one is looking at the data. There is slight overhead though with using a char instead of an integer column (as collations/character sets have to be considered).

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Personally I would opt typically for `TINYINT` over `CHAR(1)`. Though `CHAR(1)` can occasionally be useful, in which case you would want to set the column to a binary Collation, such as `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`, and use characters a-z and A-Z as I believe they are the same across all Code Pages (not 100% sure about the EBCDIC ones, though, but still).

Comment: @srutzky: Thank you, I opted for TINYINT too. I have a problem with [this case](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140604/implementing-subtype-of-a-subtype-in-type-subtype-design-pattern-with-mutually-e) where (in my gut feeling), I should somehow optimize the subclasses that have common attribute `E` (please read the question, it is short and, in my humble opinion, concise). Thank you for the tip...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff How would you perform insert queries for this design? Suppose If you want to insert a new row or rows in bulk in any of the subtype.