# Distinguish between "take-away orders" and "orders for a table"

Tags: database-design

I have these tables:

[image]

I have to distinguish an order: it can be **an order to a specific table** or **a take-away order**. If it's an order to a specific table, I just need to store **table number** and **the number of people** that are on that table currently; If it is a take-away order, I just need to store **the name of the person who "booked" the order** (they told me they don't want surname and the time, just the name).

How can I do that? I thought to add 3 columns to Orders table, `table_number (INT)`, `n_people_in_table (INT)`, `take_away_name (VARCHAR)`, so if the order is for a table I would populate the `table_number` and `n_people_in_table` fields, and the `take_away_name` would be be NULL. Otherwise, if the order is a take-away order, I would populate `take_away_name` field; `table_number` and `n_people_in_table` fields would be NULL.

But I don't like this solution very much and I don't think it is an elegant way. Which is the best way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing subtype of a subtype in type/subtype design pattern with mutually exclusive subclasses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140604/implementing-subtype-of-a-subtype-in-type-subtype-design-pattern-with-mutually-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isn't the best way of doing it. There are different pro and cons in each solution. And this can change in future.

I would use discrete tables for each order type, with referential integrity:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
      order_id          INT      not null
        PRIMARY KEY
    , order_date        DATETIME not null
)

CREATE TABLE TableOrders 
(
      order_id          INT      not null
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES 
        Orders(order_id)
    , table_number      INT      not null
    , n_people_in_table INT      not null
)

CREATE TABLE TakeAwayOrders 
(
      order_id          INT      not null
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES 
        Orders(order_id)
    , take_away_name    VARCHAR(30) not null
)
```

In future you can add other types of orders; an example:

```
CREATE TABLE ShippedOrders 
(
      order_id               INT not null
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES 
        Orders(order_id)
    , name                   VARCHAR(100) not null
    , address_id             INT not null
    , delivery_timerange_id  INT not null
)
```