# Database design: specifications for different types of products

Tags: database-design

I have table *product* that contains all types of products.
[image]
Each product has a set of specifications **unique** for that particular product type. For example if the product is smartphone its specifications would include ram, storage size, cpu etc., but if the product is, for example, clothing its specifications would include the type of fabric, size etc.
What would be the proper way to design the database? Currently I see two options:

1. Create a table for each product type. For example smartphones would be in a table named *smartphones* and clothes would be in a table named *clothing*.[image]
2. Have generic table *product* that will contain all types of products and generic table *specifications* that will contain specifications for all types of products. [image]

What would you recommend me? How would you design the database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing subtype of a subtype in type/subtype design pattern with mutually exclusive subclasses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140604/implementing-subtype-of-a-subtype-in-type-subtype-design-pattern-with-mutually-e)

Comment: Neither of these solutions are great. The main options are: Table-Per-Type, where each type gets its own table, but the common `product` columns would be in a single table with 1:1 FK relationships (and a `Type` discriminator column). Or Single-Table, where all columns are in a single table with appropriate `CHECK` constraints. Side note: 9 image columns seems to break normalization rules, you should probably have a separate `ProductImage` table.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the link. Never heard of normalization rules, I'm googling it now.

Comment: Use either solid table which stores NULLs for non-applicable columns or EAV pattern. PS. Normalize photos/images to separate table joined M:N to products table.